# Get a list of the deleted files since the last commit

Tags: git

What I want is to get a list of files that where deleted since the last commit to git.

Currently I'm getting a list of all the changed files since the last commit which I then use to upload those files to my server through jenkins. However I couldn't find anything on getting a list of deleted files since the last commit.

So what I'm trying to achieve is getting a list of the removed files and remove these from the server through jenkins.

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are: `git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only HEAD`

Comment: an additional question to this filter. Is it also possible to select EVERYTHING BUT the removed files?

Comment: Sure: `git diff --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB --name-only HEAD`. For the meaning of each filter character, read `git help diff` and search for `diff-filter`. Ah, or even better, just seen it myself: `git diff --diff-filter=d --name-only HEAD`. Lowercase means exclude uppercase means  include.

Comment: I found the page indeed but I just entered the values wrong apparantly haha. However I'm having a problem. I'm comparing 2 commits with eachother to put the files that changed in a zip and these are then transfered to my ftp. However when I delete files it will try to add those files to a zip (which causes an error obviously). But when I make my command like this: `git archive --output=publish/update.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only $PREVIOUS $CURRENT)` it will just grab ALL the files that are present. Any clue what I should change?

Comment: What's the matter with adding `--diff-filter=d`? Works fine for me, as long as there are not too many changed lines so that the command line is too long as there is a maximum limit for command length.

Comment: when I add --diff-filter=d the same thing happens it just seems to grab all the files that are in the git. I think it doesn't look at the differences between the 2 commits that are specified. So what happens is it will look at everything that ever changed and add it to the zip. This only happens with the filter in there. `$PREVIOUS` and `CURRENT` are the commit id's that I'm comparing against eachother

Comment: Maybe those are not set correctly. I tested your command with `--diff-filter=d` added and giving two concrete commit-ish to compare and it created a ZIP with exactly the three modified files, ignoring the one deleted file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121806/discussion-between-nosixties-and-vampire).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

`git diff --diff-filter=D --summary`

it will give you list of deleted files one per line like following:

`delete mode 100644 path/deleted.file`